# Remove columns with all NA values in multiple dataframes

Tags: r, missing-data

I have >100 dataframes loaded into R with some columns containing 100% missing data which I would like to remove from all dataframes. In the below example with 3 dataframes, I would like to remove the columns a, d, h since they contain all missing values but keep all the dataframe names and everything else the same. How can this be done?

```
df1 <- data.frame(`a` = rep(NA, 5), `b` = seq(1, 5, 1), `c` = letters[1:5])
df2 <- data.frame(`d` = rep(NA, 5), `e` = seq(2, 6, 1), `f` = letters[6:10])
df3 <- data.frame(`g` = rep(5, 5), `h` = rep(NA, 5), `i` = letters[6:10])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the data frames in a list and use an anonymous function.

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern='^df\\d$'))

lapply(lst, \(x) x[, !apply(is.na(x), 2, all)])
# $df1
#   b c
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
# 3 3 c
# 4 4 d
# 5 5 e
# 
# $df2
#   e f
# 1 2 f
# 2 3 g
# 3 4 h
# 4 5 i
# 5 6 j
# 
# $df3
#   g i
# 1 5 f
# 2 5 g
# 3 5 h
# 4 5 i
# 5 5 j
```

Comment: This seems to work very well. Two questions arises:
1. How do I do if dataframes have different names (i.e. not all starts with df)?
2. How do I overwrite the actual dataframes to the new dataframes without the 100% missing data columns?

Comment: @PontusHedberg You can use a hardcoded _named_ list of your dfs `lst <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, ...)`. 2. should be answered in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75426741/6574038).

Answer (score 0):

[R - how to check if all rows in a dataframe are NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130169/r-how-to-check-if-all-rows-in-a-dataframe-are-nan)

```
library(purrr) 

map(mget(ls()), ~ .x[, colSums(is.na(.x)) < nrow(.x)])  

$df1
  b c
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
5 5 e

$df2
  e f
1 2 f
2 3 g
3 4 h
4 5 i
5 6 j

$df3
  g i
1 5 f
2 5 g
3 5 h
4 5 i
5 5 j
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`. First put all your data.frames in a list. Then loop over the list elements with `select`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_df_list %>%
    map(\(x) select(x, where(~
!all(is.na(.x))))
```

To create the list of data frames, we can use `mget`.

```
my_df_list <- mget(ls()) %>%
    keep(is.data.frame)
```

Comment: Seems to work well! How do you create a list of all the dataframes/tibbles in the global environment?

Comment: For that se can use mget, as show in other answers.

Comment: Please see the updated answer with the code to get all data.frames from the global environment